# Unit Testing Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

In my project I am following Repository Pattern. My Repositories talk to the Persistence Layer and I am using Entity Framework as the ORM.

Currently, in my unit tests, I code directly against the Persistence Layer and as a result any test runs directly against the DB. So, if I test for insertion, it actually inserts the data into the Database.

I want to know how can I test without having to worry about database getting modified?

Is there a way I can do in-memory database testing?

Thanks

I have created a Database schema similar to actual one in my App_Data and then I tried implementing it like this -

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {

        //TODO:  in TestCleanup, do a rollback to revert any changes performed during the test.
        Database.SetInitializer<LogViewerDbContextFake>(new LogViewerInitializer());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_Should_Return_List_Of_Applications()
    {
        // Arrange
        LogViewerDbContext testDbContext = new LogViewerDbContextFake();
        ApplicationRepository sut = new ApplicationRepositoryImpl(testDbContext);

        // Act
        List<string> failure = sut.Get();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(4, failure.Count);
    }

 internal class LogViewerInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LogViewerDbContextFake>
{
    protected override void Seed(LogViewerDbContextFake context)
    {
        List<LogEntry> logEntries = new List<LogEntry>()
        {
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 1,
                Application = "Application 1"
            },
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 2,
                Application = "Application 2"
            },
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 3,
                Application = "Application 3"
            },
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 4,
                Application = "Application 4"
            },
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 5,
                Application = "Application 2"
            },
            new LogEntry{
                Id = 6,
                Application = "Application 2"
            }
        };

        logEntries.ForEach(s => context.LogEntries.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Even though test ran and passed, LogViewerInitializer did not insert any records in the App_Data\Database. So, I was wondering what is the logic behind and how exactly things are getting executed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) block to avoid committing data to the database.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     // test goes here

     db.SaveChanges();

    // assertions    
}
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. IMO the unit tests should never even try to access the database. If you are you are not unit testing.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Unit testing EF dependent code won't uncover many if the problems if you do not hit the database and use Mocks/Fakes. For example using the `Last` extension method on LINQ-to-Entities won't work but works with LINQ-to-Objects. So your unit tests will pass but the code is incorrect. There are many such examples.

Comment: Thats actually integration testing. You need to test logic in isolation, it shouldn't be tested at the same time as testing between the boundaries of systems such as in this case

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Point being doing a test that hits the database is better that doing a test with fakes/Mocks when it comes to testing EF repositories.

Comment: I think its much more important to test your application logic using unit tests. These cover your business logic. Integration tests are also important but should be approached in a separate manor. For example with an integration test you would normally instantiate a DB for the test, run your test then revert/destroy the db. Integration tests test the system end to end. Unit tests test logic in isolation

Comment: @LukeMcGregor In this context of the problem, logic involves the access of db through EF.

Comment: @Luke: To make it clear. There are no unit test for repositories, there are only integration tests for repositories. Unit testing repository doesn't make sense because repository itself is wrapper of EF code which cannot be easily faked.

Comment: The question wasnt about testing vs the DB it was about making it so that you dont need to. "Is there a way I can do in-memory database testing?"

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I agree the goal isnt to unit test the repository. The goal is to use a repository pattern to put a layer in the middle so that you dont need to test DB. By structuring your app in this way you can easily swap out your EF connector for another (such as in memory) and test without the DB. It also give you other nice to haves such as being able to run your app vs an in memory set for rapid development/debugging.

Comment: @Luke: But you will swap whole repository layer, not connector to EF.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka in my implementation the repository is split in two, a presentation/query layer and a datasource layer. This allows the application to query without needing to be aware of the specific storage tech while providing some useful bits

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Try the example I gave in the first comment with your **implementation** to check whether it caches the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a mocking framework such as Rhinomocks or MOQ to mock out the persistence layer?

Alternately you can make the argument that you are actually doing end to end testing and remove the data from the database after the test is run. You do this by running a post and pre sql scripts before and after running your test using attributes. If you are using an AOP framework such as PostSharp, this makes it very easy. If not you can still do it using contextbound objects as I have explained [here](http://www.chaitanyaonline.net/2011/09/25/improving-integration-tests-in-net-by-using-attributes-to-execute-sql-scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

I built my own repository framework to do this using ninject and EF. Take a look here if you are interested, i also have an example of how to use my repository framework to produce simple unit tests.

http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/10/staticvoid-repository-pattern-nuget.html